# Javascript/jQuery make a variable accessible outside of loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, variables, scope

I have a loop that I'm using to alter a string that looks like this

```
  for (var key in streets) {
    var re = new RegExp(key, 'gi');
    var address2_2 = address2.replace(re, streets[key]).replace(/\s/g, '');
  }
```

If I use the variable 'address2_2' within the loop it's fine and the loop performs it's job well. The problem is I need to be able to access this outside of the loop. I've tried every combination of things I could think of to retrieve it like the following snippets.

```
  var address2_2 = '';
  for (var key in streets) {
    var re = new RegExp(key, 'gi');
    address2_2 = address2.replace(re, streets[key]).replace(/\s/g, '');
  }

  var address2_2 = '';
  for (var key in streets) {
    var re = new RegExp(key, 'gi');
    address2_2 = address2.replace(re, streets[key]).replace(/\s/g, '');
    return address2_2;
  }

  for (var key in streets) {
    var re = new RegExp(key, 'gi');
    window.address2_2 = address2.replace(re, streets[key]).replace(/\s/g, '');
  }
```

There have been more combinations but I can't remember them all. I just need to be able to use 'address2_2' in an if statement outside of this loop. Any help is appreciated as always. Thanks

Edit: Here's a [terrible jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ay7rse4/) I made quickly for those that asked

The full code is something like this

```
var streets = {
  "AVE": "AVENUE",
  "BLDG": "BUILDING",
  "BLVD": "BOULEVARD",
  "CIR": "CIRCLE",
  "CLL": "CALLE",
  "CR": "COUNTY ROAD",
  "CTR": "CENTER",
  "CTY": "CITY",
  "DR": "DRIVE",
  "EXT": "EXTENSION",
  "FM": "FARM ROAD",
  "HC": "HIGHWAY CONTRACT",
  "HWY": "HIGHWAY",
  "LN": "LANE",
  "MT": "MOUNT",
  "PL": "PLACE",
  "PLZ": "PLAZA",
  "PKWY": "PARKWAY",
  "PT": "POINT",
  "RD": "ROAD",
  "RT": "ROUTE",
  "RTE": "ROUTE",
  "SQ": "SQUARE",
  "SR": "STATE ROUTE",
  "ST": "STREET",
  "STE": "SUITE",
  "TR": "TRAIL",
  "WY": "WAY",
};

var address2 = '850 BULL ST';

  for (var key in streets) {
    re = new RegExp(key, 'gi');
    address2_2 = address2.replace(re, streets[key]).replace(/\s/g, '');
    console.log(address2_2);
  }
  console.log(address2_2);
```

Comment: Are these snippets working ?

Comment: can you post the whole code or jsfiddle?

Comment: No the snippets aren't working.

Answer (score 2):

In javaScript there's only `function` scope, meaning, declaring a variable inside a loop, put's the variable declaration outside the loop automatically.

```
var address2_2, // undefined
    re; // undefined

for (var key in streets) {
    re = new RegExp(key, 'gi');
    address2_2 = address2.replace(re, streets[key]).replace(/\s/g, '');
}

// then use it in an if else claus
if (address2_2){
    // do something
}
```

**EDIT:**

Oh right, the same goes on for the `var key`. Just in case you're wondering. And so they're bound to the closest function or window object if no function can be found.

**EDIT 2:**

To also provide a solution, perhaps fork this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/thd4g5vv/)

Better is to split the address on spaces, and then compare with the array.
A short solution to your problem in case of multiple occurrences ...

```
var streets = {/**/},
    input = '850 BULL ST PLZ',
    address = input.split(' '),
    arr = [],
    i = 0,
    chunk;

for (; i < address.length; i++) {
    chunk = streets[address[i]] || address[i]; // undefined or original
    arr.push(chunk);
}

$("#loop").append(address.join('<br />'));
$("#result").append(arr.join(' '));
```